# Correct grit and sander for sanding a cedar railing?

Tags: deck, sanding

We have a cedar railing around a deck. The railing needs to be sanded prior to applying a water sealer. Two questions:

1. What is the best grit of sandpaper to use? I read that using too fine of a grit might make it more difficult to seal, but the article did not provide much guidance after that suggestion.
2. What type of sander should I use? Is a random orbital sander OK, or is there a different preferred type?

Thank you for your input!

Comment: It really depends on how rough the surface is and the type of sander being used. With a orbital I don't often go very corse because they don't move as far as a belt sander but both will work. 200 grit may work for your needs but you probably don't want to go finer than 400 grit.

Answer (score -1):

cedar is soft, grit not critical, I would use 150